# How to determine if 4th day of the month (Mon and Sun not included)

Tags: python, date, datetime

I know pandas has `weekday()` which returns the day of the week as an integer (0 as Monday and 6 Sunday) but I can't think of solution that will return `True` if the current date today is the 4th day of the month while disregarding Sunday and Monday, considering the schedule runs only from Tuesday to Saturday.

Is there anyone came across with this?

Comment: Hint: use `and`.

Comment: Isn't this as simple as `if (day == 4 and (weekday not in (0, 6))` ?

Comment: @Max I think OP wants to find the 4th *business day* of the month, which that won’t do.

Comment: In general that should be a pretty simple algorithm. If it’s Friday and it’s the 4th, then it’s also the 4th business day. If it’s Tuesday, it has to be the 6th for it to be the 4th business day. You just need to add/subtract 2 for specific days of the week… I’ll leave the details up as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Chesterrae: Do you mean 4th _business_ day of the month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will help you do that by creating a date sequence excluding weekends. Please note that the input should be a date object (e.g. datetime.now().date())

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def is_4th(d):
    # get month start
    month_start = datetime(d.year,d.month,1).date()
    # create a date sequence from start of month excluding the weekends
    date_seq = [(month_start + timedelta(days=i)) for i in range(0, 7) if (month_start+timedelta(days=i)).weekday() not in [5,6]]
    # if 4th day in the sequence is equal to the date then return true else false
    if d ==date_seq[3]:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the run sequence starts from tue-sat so I'll just have to change the not in [5, 6] to [0, 6].

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to solve problems like these is just to build a table:
For each day of the week, ask yourself:  If the first of the month falls on that day of the week, what day of the month/day of the week do I want my event to happen on.

Write a predicate that returns true on precisely those 7 day-of-week/day-of-month combinations and nothing else.